# Изменение display в зависимости от id на странице

Tags: javascript

Нужно изменить значение свойства display в зависимости от того, какой сейчас div id на странице.
При попытках найти что-то подобное, натыкался только на реализацию при помощи кнопок. Мне же нужно немного иное
Пример: если человек авторизирован, то

```html
<div id="auth">
Приветствую, username.
</div>
```

если нет, то

```html
<div id="noauth">
<a class="btn1" href="#">Авторизация</a>
<a class="btn2" href="#">Регистрация</a>
</div>
```

*какой-то код*

```html
<div id="hide">текст</div>
```

Тоесть, если на странице сейчас *id="noauth"*, то *id="hide"* - *display: none*. В случае если *id="auth"*, то *block*.
Спасибо!

Comment: Логика в принципе будет похожа на реализацию с кнопками, только Вам не нужно будет слушать клик, и просто проверить если элемент с определенным ID существует, отобразить его.

Answer (score 2):

> `Приветствую, username.`

Вот в том месте, где ты определяешь, что за `username`, надо сделать проверку и рендерить только нужный блок. Либо ненужному поставить атрибут hidden. Только не забуlь в css прописать

```
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}
```